# CodeIgniter - default value for CKEditor

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor

i need to use a default value for an instance of ckeditor into my project.
In my controller i load the helper for ckedotir and ckfinder in this way:

```
$this->load->library('ckeditor');
$this->load->library('ckfinder');
$this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url().'asset/ckeditor/';
$this->ckeditor->config['toolbar'] = array(
                    array( 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-','Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo','-','NumberedList','BulletedList' )
                );
    $this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'it';
    $this->ckeditor->config['width'] = '730px';
    $this->ckeditor->config['height'] = '300px';            
    $this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor,'../../asset/ckfinder/');
```

then into my view i use:

```
echo $this->ckeditor->editor("area1");
echo $this->ckeditor->editor("area2");
```

to load the form but i can't understand how set default value...can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value is the second parameter of the `editor()` method.

```
echo $this->ckeditor->editor("area1","default value1");
echo $this->ckeditor->editor("area2","default value2");
```